# Color gradient to two sets of curves

Tags: plotting, color

Maybe it's a basic question but how can I achieve a gradient color style on the curves above the origin and a different style on the curves below the origin? I tried the following:

```
values1 = {0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1};
values2 = {0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1};
Plot[{values1 + x^2, -values2 - x^2}, {x, 1, 2}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Thick, Dashed}]
```

[image]

To change the color I would have to go graph by graph but how would I achieve the gradient? I appreciate suggestions or comments

Comment: I'd say the easiest, most straightforward way is to generate the two plots separately and combine them with `Show[]`. Also, the nature of the desired gradient is unclear to me. Do you want each curve to be a single color but changing according to a gradient? Or do you want each curve changing color along its length according to some function of the coordinates? I assume the former, but the answers so far show the latter.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Exactly, I want each curve to be a single color but change according to a gradient. I'm sorry if it wasn't entirely clear.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maybe something along these lines...

```
Plot[
  {values1 + x^2, -values2 - x^2}, {x, 1, 2}, 
  PlotStyle -> {Thick, Dashed}, 
  ColorFunction -> (Function[{x, y}, If[y > 0, Blend[{Red, Blue}, x], Blend[{Orange, Green}, x]]]), 
  ColorFunctionScaling -> {True, False}]
```

[image]

**Update based on comments**

```
Plot[
  {values1 + x^2, -values2 - x^2}, {x, 1, 2}, 
  PlotStyle -> {Thick, Dashed},
  ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y}, If[y > 0, Blend[{Red, Blue}, y - x^2], Blend[{Green, Orange}, Abs[y] - x^2]]], 
   ColorFunctionScaling -> False]
```

[image]

If your `values` weren't between 0 and 1, this probably won't give what you want, and in that case you could use `Rescale`.

Comment: Note this is not [what the OP asked for](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/300795/color-gradient-to-two-sets-of-curves?noredirect=1#comment740383_300795). I assume you can adjust.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Thanks :)!

Answer (score 6):

```
$Version

(* "14.0.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (December 13, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

values1 = {0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1};
values2 = {0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1};

Show[
 Plot[#[[1]], {x, 1, 2},
    PlotStyle -> #[[2]],
    ColorFunction -> #[[3]],
    PlotLegends -> BarLegend[Automatic,
      LegendLabel -> #[[4]]]] & /@
  Transpose[{
    {values1 + x^2, -values2 - x^2},
    {Automatic, Dashed},
    {"Rainbow", "SunsetColors"},
    {"Upper", "Lower"}}],
 PlotRange -> All,
 AxesOrigin -> {1, 0}]
```

[image]